# Fatal error, cannot reasign this

Tags: php, cakephp

Currently trying to use CakePHP to find items to populate two lists with, but I'm getting this error. I'm fairly new to PHP and CakePHP in particular, but I think it might be a problem with my array?

```
Error: Cannot re-assign $this   
File: /var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/app/Controller/CompaniesController.php 
Line: 75
```

Here's the function that's causing problems:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Company->create();
        if ($this->Company->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $users = array(
        'User' => $this->Company->User->find('list'),
        'Address' => $this->Company->User->find('list'));
    $this = array(
        'users' => set(compact('users')),
        'addresses' => set(compact('addresses')),
        );
}
```

Comment: `$this = array(`... what are you trying to assign here? What properties are these array elements intended to modify in `$this`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm trying to set multiple `$this->set(compact('users'));` Should I have it something more like `$findr = array(
   'users' => $this->set(compact('users')),
   'addresses' => $this->set(compact('addresses')),
   );` instead?

Comment: So you are trying to call `$this->set(compact('key'))` for all keys in `array('users', 'addresses')`?

Comment: (I don't know CakePHP conventions well, sorry)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Something similar, I'm trying to the id of each table, which is referenced earlier on in the function.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is a predefined variable in PHP, it already has a value and you can't change it. You can use `$this` to manipulate the current object only.

More information about objects (and what is possible with `$this`) is available on: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Just use $this->set( compact() ); and include the list of variables you want to pass to the view.

$this->set( compact('users','addresses') );

Comment: Feel so close! Only thing is `addresses` comes from a different table, so how would I reference that too?

I tried:

`$users = $this->Company->User->find('list');`

`$addresses = $this->Company->Address->find('list');`

`$this->set(compact('users', 'addresses'));`

But it didn't work.